# Ideal Java Data Structure for Streaming data to QT Creator

Tags: java, qt, stream

does anyone knows, what is the best way to stream Data (like Strings, Int, Reals, ....) betweem a java app and an QT app. I try it with QT:QDataStream and JAVA:DataOutputSttream, but theres an difference in the Byte Arrays. Can someone help me??

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Use XML or JSON as both languages will be using the same standard. I would do it in JSON as it should be able to encapsulate byte arrays and the other types you've mentioned easily. If you're using Qt 5 then you can simple use [QJsonDocument::fromRawData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html#fromRawData). Otherwise you can find libraries for both Java and Qt in [json.org](http://json.org/).